# What specifications is the ISRO crew module fabricated to?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, isro, developing-space-programs, crew-module, human-rating

http://www.thehindubusinessline.com/news/science/human-space-flight-prog-hal-hands-over-crew-module-assembly-to-isro/article5685195.ece

writes to say

> Hindustan Aeronautics Ltd (HAL) has handed over the first ‘Crew Module Structural Assembly’ for the ‘Human Space Flight Program’ to ISRO's Vikram Sarabhai Space Centre (VSSC).

I'm assuming some specifications are universal (and rigid)

- Temperature tolerance
- Heat absorption/dissipation
- Pressure tolerance
- Viewports

Other specifications are soft (design/fabrication trade-off)

- Internal volume
- Crew member sizes
- Subassembly/systems

Which brings me to my question

- How many crew can the ISRO crew module accommodate?
- For how long?
- Is the crew module provided with an air-lock, dock, and escape mechanism?

Answer (score 5):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISRO_Orbital_Vehicle:

> The Indian manned spacecraft temporarily named Orbital Vehicle is intended to be the basis of the indigenous Indian human spaceflight program. The capsule will be designed to carry three people, and a planned upgraded version will be equipped with rendezvous and docking capability. In its maiden manned mission, ISRO's largely autonomous 3-ton capsule will orbit the Earth at 248 miles (400 km) altitude for up to seven days with a two-person crew on board.

[image: ISRO Orbital Vehicle]